# How to update multiple records from one page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

how to update the field(Next_Step__c ) of multiple records via one Visualforce page, i have write save method but its not update the multiple records

vf page:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="contact" contentType="{!IF(isExport = true, 'application/vnd.ms-excel#Emailstatus.xls','')}" showHeader="false" extensions="DisplayEmailstatusController">

<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SortableJS}"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    root
    {
        display: block;
    }

    th.sortable
    {
        color: #666;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

        th.sortable:hover
        {
            color: black;
        }

    th.sorted-asc, th.sorted-desc
    {
        color: black;
        background-color: cadetblue;
    }
</style>
<apex:form >
  <!--- This block is used to select the filter ----->
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePb" title="HTML Email Status Report">
            <apex:pageblockSection id="thepbs">
               <apex:inputText value="{!templateName}" label="Email Template Name" id="theTextInput"/>

                <apex:inputText label="Campaign ID" value="{!searchStr}" id="sdd" />
      <!--          <apex:inputField label="SendDate" value="{!con.Send_Date__c}"/>  -->
               <apex:inputField label="Send from Date" value="{!con.Sent_From_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Send to Date" value="{!con.Sent_To_Date__c}" />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
                <Right> <apex:commandButton action="{!getDetails}" value="Search" /></right>
                <left> <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" /></left>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandLink value="Click here to download" action="{!exportExl}" style="margin-left: 500px;color:blue;" rendered="{!(isExport = false)}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock >
  <table border="1" class="sortable" style="width:100%;border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;">

        <tr style = "font-weight:bold;background:#B6B3A5 ;width: 20px; height: 10px;">
           <th style="text-align: justify;" width="5%" align="right"><center>Contact ID</center></th>
           <th><center>Title</center></th>
           <th><center>Name</center></th>
           <th><center>Email</center></th>
           <th><center>Direct Phone</center></th>
           <th><center>Other Phone</center></th>
           <th><center>Task Id</center></th>
           <th><center>Status</center></th>
           <th><center>Action taken</center></th>
           <th><center>Next Step</center></th>
           <th><center>Next Step Owner</center></th>
           <th><center>Comment</center></th> 
           <th><div style="word-wrap:break-word;"><center>Next Step Due Date</center></div> </th>
           <th><center>Inside Sales Reps</center></th>
           <th><center>Subject</center></th> 
           <th><center>Sent Date</center></th>
           <th><center>First Open Date</center></th>
           <th><center>Last Open Date</center></th>
           <th><center>Times Opened</center></th>
           <th><center>Email Template Name</center></th>
           <th><center>EmailBouncedDate</center></th>
           <th><center>EmailBouncedReason</center></th>            
        </tr>

            <apex:repeat value="{!lstContacts}" var="rec"> 
               <apex:repeat value="{!rec.EmailStatuses}" var="emailStatus">
                 <tr style = "width: 20px; height: 10px;">
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;"><apex:outputlink value="/{!rec.ID}" target="_blank" style="color:blue">{!rec.id} </apex:outputlink></td> 
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.title}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.name}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.email}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.phone}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.Otherphone}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;"><apex:outputlink value="/{!rec.Task_ID__c}" target="_blank" style="color:blue">{!rec.Task_ID__c} </apex:outputlink></td>
                    <td style ="width: 20px; height: 10px;">{!rec.Status__c}</td>
                    <td><apex:inputfield style="width:80px; height:90px;" value="{!rec.Action_taken__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputText style="width:80px; height:90px; word-wrap:break-word;" value="{!insertStr}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputfield style="width:90px; height:90px; word-wrap:break-word;" value="{!rec.Next_Step_Owner__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputfield style="width:80px; height: 90px; word-wrap:break-word;" value="{!rec.Comment__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputfield style="word-wrap:break-word; width:70px;" value="{!rec.Next_Step_Due_Date__c}"/></td>                   
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;">{!rec.ISO__c}</td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:300px;">{!emailStatus.task.Subject}</td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;"><apex:outputTEXT value=" {0,date,MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a}"> <apex:param value="{!emailStatus.createdDate}"/></apex:outputTEXT></td>                         
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;"><apex:outputText value=" {0,date,MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a}"> <apex:param value="{!emailStatus.firstOpenDate}"/></apex:outputText></td>                         
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;"><apex:outputText value=" {0,date,MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a}"> <apex:param value="{!emailStatus.lastOpenDate}"/></apex:outputText></td>                         
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;"><center>{!emailStatus.timesOpened}</center></td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;">{!emailStatus.emailTemplateName}</td>  
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;"><apex:outputText value=" {0,date,EEE MMM d, yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!rec.EmailBouncedDate}"/></apex:outputText></td>                                                
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40px;">{!rec.EmailBouncedReason}</td> 
                 </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
           </apex:repeat>
      </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class DisplayEmailstatusController{ 
    public boolean isExport {get;set;}
    public contact con{get;set;}
    public String templateName{get;set;}
    public String searchStr{get;set;}
    public String insertStr{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> lstContacts{get;set;}
    public Date createdFromDateFilter{get;set;}
    public Date createdToDateFilter{get;set;}
    List<string> conditions = new List<string>();   
    public DisplayEmailstatusController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){                                               
        con = new contact ();
        createdFromDateFilter = Date.today().adddays(-30);
        con.Sent_From_Date__c = createdFromDateFilter;
        lstContacts = new List<Contact>();   
        createdToDateFilter = Date.today();
        con.Sent_To_Date__c = createdToDateFilter; 
    }

    public PageReference getDetails(){
        conditions.clear();
        String EmailTemp = '';
        string innerquery = 'select contactid from campaignmember';
        system.debug(innerquery);
        if(con.Sent_From_Date__c!=null){
            createdFromDateFilter = con.Sent_From_Date__c;            
        } 

        if(con.Sent_To_Date__c!=null ){
            createdToDateFilter = con.Sent_To_Date__c;            
        }

        if(templateName != null){
            EmailTemp = '%'+templateName+'%';
            for(Contact con : [SELECT id,Title, name,Task_ID__c,Comment__c,phone,OtherPhone,email,ISO__c,Status__c,Action_taken__c,Next_Step__c,Next_Step_Owner__c,
                    Next_Step_Due_Date__c,EmailBouncedDate,EmailBouncedReason,(SELECT id,taskId, createdDate,task.Subject,firstOpenDate,lastOpenDate,timesOpened,
                    emailTemplateName FROM EmailStatuses where createdDate >= :createdFromDateFilter and createdDate <= :createdToDateFilter  
                    and timesOpened>0  )FROM contact where id in(select contactid from campaignmember where campaignid=:searchStr) ]){
                     if(con.EmailStatuses != null && con.EmailStatuses.size() >0){
                        lstContacts.add(con);
                    }                   
            }  
       } 
       return null;       
    }   
    public pagereference exportExl(){
        isExport=true;    
        return null;
    }  
    public PageReference saveDetails(){
       for(Contact con : [SELECT id,Title, name,Task_ID__c,Comment__c,phone,OtherPhone,email,ISO__c,Status__c,Action_taken__c,Next_Step__c,Next_Step_Owner__c,
                    Next_Step_Due_Date__c,EmailBouncedDate,EmailBouncedReason,(SELECT id,taskId, createdDate,task.Subject,firstOpenDate,lastOpenDate,timesOpened,
                    emailTemplateName FROM EmailStatuses where createdDate >= :createdFromDateFilter and createdDate <= :createdToDateFilter  
                    and timesOpened>0  )FROM contact where id in(select contactid from campaignmember where campaignid=:searchStr) ]){
                      system.debug('con---'+con.Next_Step__c);  
                      con.Next_Step__c = insertStr;
                //    con.Next_Step_Owner__c=
                //    con.Next_Step_Due_Date__c=
                //    con.Comment__c=
                      update con;     

       }                   
                        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result into contact list and modify the value in inside list and update that list later again. When you change the **con** contact object inside the for loop, the list also get update has it is an reference to **contactList**.

```
public PageReference saveDetails(){
  List<contact> contactList=[SELECT id,Title, name,Task_ID__c,Comment__c,phone,OtherPhone,email,ISO__c,Status__c,Action_taken__c,Next_Step__c,Next_Step_Owner__c,
                    Next_Step_Due_Date__c,EmailBouncedDate,EmailBouncedReason,(SELECT id,taskId, createdDate,task.Subject,firstOpenDate,lastOpenDate,timesOpened,
                    emailTemplateName FROM EmailStatuses where createdDate >= :createdFromDateFilter and createdDate <= :createdToDateFilter  
                    and timesOpened>0  )FROM contact where id in(select contactid from campaignmember where campaignid=:searchStr) ];        
       for(Contact con :contactList )
                      con.Next_Step__c = insertStr;    

        update contactList;
        return null;
  }
```

Comment: i have tried above code but it give next step blank .

Comment: @shwetathakur  did you check "insertStr" value in log file?

Comment: yes i have checked,this also return blank

Comment: @shwetathakur insertStr came from where ? its the issue with insertStr sending value

Comment: i have define string variable to store the next step .

Comment: @shwetathakur its bcoz you have used insertStr inside repeat, All the inputText box you have allocated with insertStr value.

Comment: @shwetathakur You should creating wrapper class and pass inside the repeater.

Comment: @shwetathakur Share screenshot of the Visualforce page ,how it look.